# how to write vertica trigger

Tags: asp.net, sql, triggers, vertica

Am new to vertica. My need is to write a trigger to insert into the history table whenever table update occurs.

It is simply possible in MSSQL. like vise is my need and can any body suggest some direct links or details the steps am there is less time for me to investigate into and the searches didn't resulted productive.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vertica doesn't support triggers. This may seem strange if you're coming from another database platform, but the fact is Vertica was designed for analytical reporting applications, while triggers are more about transaction processing.

It is my impression that most Vertica users (including my company) process transactional updates to data in a more traditional Relation Database or other system and periodically batch-load Vertica with any updates. Any business rules or data validation requiring a trigger or other procedural logic should occur on this other, primary database system.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into external UDF. 
sky's the limit !

Answer (score 0):

Vertica is  of no use if your requirement needs Analytical Functions creations. Its meant for acting as Front schema from where you can select and show faster then oracle and other DB's.